# Elastic Beanstalk deployment of Spring Boot application - where to put the external application.properties

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, deployment, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Spring Boot application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using AWSCLI. I want to put an external *application.properties* file containing customer specification configurations (database credentials, etc.) in the same directory of the application. The application should pick up this properties file. How can I accomplish that? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

### [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)

This project allows you to use an external, centralized configuration repository for one or more applications. You don't need to rebuild your application if a property changes. You can simply change the property in your configuration repository and even push the changes to all of your applications.

See this [Getting Started Guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/).

This above approach is what I would recommend for the scenario you described.  I would not bother with having a separate directory on the application server for your configuration files.  Spring Cloud Config is a great approach as it solves the problem you described and a few more.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively specify them in an application-prod property like

```
server.port=5000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${RDS_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and specify an environment variable called SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE with the value prod making the beanstalk smart enough to pick values from out there.